# Using string.replace() to alter an URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input text box on a web page that asks for the  name of a city, and a submit button right beside it. In my JavaScript file I have a variable var = url that holds the http address for getting data from openweathermap. I would like to use string.replace(currentCity, inputTextCity) to alter the existing city in that url. Is this the right approach or is there an easier way? Would it be easier to do this with JQuery? Any help would be appreciated! My CodePen link is http://codepen.io/RDaniels34/pen/zreZwy
my JavaScript for the page is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + 'Las Cruces' + ",us&units=imperial&APPID=421da4492f2bbe838d519b0e92139dfd"; 

  $.getJSON(url, function(json) {

    var city = json.name;
    var wind = json.wind.speed;
    var temperature = json.main.temp;
    var weather = json.weather[0].main;
    $(".temp").html(temperature.toFixed(1) + " °F");
    $(".city").html(city);
    $(".wind").html("Wind " + wind + " mph");
    $(".weather").html(weather);
    switch (weather) {
      case "Rain":
        $("#icon").addClass("wi-rain");
        break;
      case "Thunderstorm":
        $("#icon").addClass("wi-thunderstorm");
        break;
      case "Drizzle":
        $("#icon").addClass("wi-raindrops");
        break;
      case "Snow":
        $("#icon").addClass("wi-snow");
        break;
      case "Atmosphere":
        $("#icon").addClass("wi-dust");
        break;
      case "Clear":
        $("#icon").addClass("wi-day-sunny");
        break;
      case "Clouds":
        $("#icon").addClass("wi-cloudy");
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

   function getUrl(city){
      url.replace('Las Cruces', city);
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: If you know how the url should formated, just create your own string using the provided city name.

Comment: I would just make it into a function or something. :)  Here's a bin for demo https://jsbin.com/xegexisixu/1/edit?html,output

Comment: I updated it to automatically encode the uri, in case you have cities that are more than one word long

Comment: if encodeURIComponent gives you trouble, there are some nice workarounds here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: It's not a Url, it's a url. el not eye.

Comment: why the neg (-1) rating? If you don't know what I'm talking about, ask and I'll give more info....The title of the question says URL..

Answer (score 1):

Insead of replace you can use a `Global Variable` like this

```
Var currentCity = "MM"

function getUrl(){
 var url="www.zzzzz.com?currentCity="+currentCity;
}
```

When hits the submit button change the value of `currentCity` varibale to user entered value and call the `getUl()`

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in plain javascript, no need for jQuery or another. But you need to do programming so as to do trivial things like this on your own. I hope I did not offended you.

```
function getUrl(city){
 return "http://someurl.com" + (city ? '?City=' + city : ''); // should add check for cases
}

getUrl('neyyork');
```